# Remove specified multiples of 60 from a number?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timer, string-formatting

So I'm trying to make a [Stopwatch program](https://github.com/sh4d0w4RCH3R415/Stopwatch/) and I can't figure out how to format the seconds and mintues correctly because every minute or 60 minutes, it doesnt reset the seconds/minutes that are displayed back to 0. I've been searching for something to just simply format the seconds/minutes in a way that makes it looks normal.

My code so far (it's just a snippet):

```
updater.Tick += (sender, e) =>
{
    hours = (int)stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalHours;
    minutes = (int)stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMinutes;
    seconds = (int)stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;

    if (hours > 24)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Time limit exceeded. Please reset Stopwatch to continue.", "Time Limit Exceeded", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    lblHours.Text = string.Format("{0:D2}", hours);
    lblMinutes.Text = string.Format("{0:D2}", minutes);
    lblSeconds.Text = string.Format("{0:D2}", seconds);

    Application.DoEvents();
};
```

If someone could help me figure this out, then I would ***really*** appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want TotalMinutes and TotalSeconds, use [Minutes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.minutes?view=net-5.0#System_TimeSpan_Minutes) and [Seconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.seconds?view=net-5.0#System_TimeSpan_Seconds) instead.

Comment: Heh, the only reason I know it right away is that I always made the same mistake too